# Matlab: Display error message and loop back to allow the user to try again

Tags: matlab, loops

I am writing a program in which the user much enter a positive integer and then a sequence starting with that value will be computed. I know how to display an error message if the value entered is below zero, but I can't figure out how to simply loop back and allow the user to try and enter again.

```
n = input('Please insert an integer ');

if n <= 0    
    error('Only integer inputs are allowed, try again.')
elseif n > 0
    (sequence is coded here)
end
```

Although I know this is simple, I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `while` loop and keep looping until the valid input has been entered. BTW, you do not want to use `error` because that will make your program terminate.  You just want to display the error, then allow the loop to go back to the beginning of the code and try again. You will also want to change the message to display to reflect that only positive integers should be put in.  You have it as just "integers" which tells the user you can put in negative integers as well:

```
while true
    n = input('Please insert an integer ');

    if n <= 0    
        disp('Only positive integer inputs are allowed, try again.')
    else
        (sequence is coded here)
        break; % Terminate the loop as we have succeeded
    end
end
```

This is basically your requirement transcribed into a `while` loop.  Some people frown on making the `while` loop explicitly infinite by setting the condition to `true` and `break`ing once you are satisfied.  A more friendly way to do this would be to first set your integer to be zero, then have the `while` condition keep looping while the integer is still zero and you'd display the message if it still is still zero or negative.  The loop will naturally break when you finally get the integer you want:

```
n = 0;
while n <= 0
    n = input('Please insert an integer: ');
    if n <= 0
        disp('Only positive integer inputs are allowed.  Try again.');
    else
        (sequence is coded here)
    end
end
```

Comment: nice I was writing the exact same answer almost word for word haha

Comment: @Benoit_11 Désolé :) J'écris sur mon clavier trop trop vite. DTF, merci pour votre +1!

Comment: Thank you all very much!

Comment: @MichaelRoberts Please consider accepting this answer if you no longer need help.